# I'm trying to consume an API restful with react

Tags: java, reactjs, rest

I have an api restful in java and it's working perfectly when I usa insomnia or postman, but I'm trying to make my front-end in react, but the status I get is "failed" and it shows me "blocked by CORS". I can solve this "block" changing my front-end from http to https, but the "failed" status still persists and when I use https on insomnia, it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

front-end code

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/PfcPubApi'
});

export default api;
```

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import api from './service/api';


function App() {
const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
const [cpf, setCpf] = useState('');
const [endereco, setEndereco] = useState('');
const [cargo, setCargo] = useState('');
const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');


  async function cadastrarFunc(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const response = await api.post('/api/item', {
          nome,
          cpf,
          endereco,
          cargo,
          senha,
      })
      console.log(response.data);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={cadastrarFunc}>
            nome:<input type="text" name="nome" value={nome} onChange={e => setNome(e.target.value)}></input>
            cpf:<input type="text" name="cpf" value={cpf} onChange={e => setCpf(e.target.value)}></input>
            endereco:<input type="text" name="endereco" value={endereco} onChange={e => setEndereco(e.target.value)}></input>
            cargo:<input type="text" name="cargo" value={cargo} onChange={e => setCargo(e.target.value)}></input>
            senha:<input type="text" name="senha" value={senha} onChange={e => setSenha(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
   </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

maybe this image can help too...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGtiP.png)

edit:
api code

```
package controle;

import java.util.Set;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(controle.FuncionarioService.class);
    }

}
```

```
package controle;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dao.FuncionarioDao;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import modelo.Funcionario;

@Path("/item")
public class FuncionarioService {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;


    public FuncionarioService() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String listAllPerson() throws SQLException {
        FuncionarioDao funcionario = new FuncionarioDao();
        return new Gson().toJson(funcionario.consultarTodosFunc());               
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{cpf}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String consultarFunc(@PathParam("cpf") String cpf) throws SQLException {
        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();
        funcionario.setCpf(cpf);

        FuncionarioDao Request = new FuncionarioDao();
        return new Gson().toJson(Request.consultarFunc(funcionario));               
    }

    @POST
    @Path("")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String cadastrarFunc(String dataPerson) throws SQLException {

        Funcionario funcionario = new Gson().fromJson(dataPerson, Funcionario.class);

        FuncionarioDao Request = new FuncionarioDao();
        funcionario = Request.cadastrarFunc(funcionario);

        return new Gson().toJson(funcionario);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String alterarFunc(String dataPerson) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Funcionario person = new Gson().fromJson(dataPerson, Funcionario.class);

        FuncionarioDao Request = new FuncionarioDao();

        return new Gson().toJson(Request.alterarFunc(person));
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{cpf}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String excluirFunc(@PathParam("cpf") String cpf) throws SQLException{
        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();
        funcionario.setCpf(cpf);


        FuncionarioDao Request = new FuncionarioDao();
        return new Gson().toJson(Request.excluirFunc(funcionario));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to enable/allow CORS on your server-side (JAVA APIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) for your API. Since you are using JAX-RS you could create a filter and set "Access-Control-Allow*" header in the response or do the same at the URL endpoint method.

The following article explains it will detail with code samples.

https://www.baeldung.com/cors-in-jax-rs

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't have Spring in my project, i just created the web service and the restful patterns

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps. Welcome to the community!!!